# How do I get placeholder values to show up in spring application form for number types

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I don't have a specific example which I know is frustrating. That said, my question is as follows: in a SpringBoot app, if I have a form for inputting numerical values of type double or int, how do I get the placeholder value to show up instead of Java's default value of 0.0 or 0?

General example:

`<p><input type="text" path="inv" th:field="*{inv}" placeholder="Inventory" class="form-control mb-4 col-4"/></p>`

Where 'inv' references an unboxed integer as I need to perform arithmetic calculations on the value.

Comment: If that is a primitive you don't as it always has a value, use the object value instead to have a `null` value which will show the placeholder.

Comment: Yep, if you want the placeholder to show up you need to use a capital I `Integer` that is null instead of an int.